# Upgrading from Windows Phone 8 project to Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c++, graphics, namespaces, directx, windows-phone-8.1

Are there any equivalent for Windows::Phone::Input::Interop and Windows::Phone::Networking::Voip namespaces in Windows phone 8.1. These are supported in Windows Phone 8 and Windows phone silverlight 8.1, but not in Windows phone 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

`Windows::Phone::Input::Interop` was specific to Silverlight <--> DX interop and is no longer needed.

For Universal apps, you should be able to use the [`CoreWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.aspx) input events or just listen to the events directly on the [`SwapChainPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel.aspx) or [`SwapChainBackgroundPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainbackgroundpanel.aspx) classes.

VoIP is not currently supported in Universal apps I'm afraid.